# Physical dimensions of Firemonkey Graphics

Tags: firemonkey

Using XE6

I am trying to figure out how to determine the physical size of the strokethickness in Firemonkey. For example what is I need a strokeThickness of 2mm? How do I set the physical thickness?

Comment: The physical thickness will depend on the physical size of the display, pixel density, resolution etc. You may be able to calculate this for a specific device but there is no generic solution.

Comment: I was hoping there might be some platform services in TPlatform to help. I had a look but didn't find anything. Looks like i've to call specific OS functions depending on the platform.